# ASP.NET Postback Crashes IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a very simple ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 application, which has a postback trigger onchange for a checkbox (autopostback=true). For some reason, in all versions of IE when I click that checkbox the broswer crashes.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckTrouble" runat="server" Text="Check this box" TextAlign="Left" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

The checkbox is in a user control, which sits on a normal old page, which uses a traditional masterpage. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, only IE is causing the grief.

Thoughts?

Comment: View the HTML source code of the page and track down the `onclick` code of the checkbox - you can add your own debug (even using alerts) and see where it crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this may have been a result of `SmartNavigation="True"`. Anyone ever see this as a cause?  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.smartnavigation.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure of the reason this would fail, but `Page.SmartNavigation` was made obsolete in .NET 2.0 onwards. Use `Page.SetFocus` and `Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack` instead. A simple search shows you're not the only one having this problem: http://www.google.com.au/search?q=smartnavigation+crash